# Oracle me detecta caracteres especiales por 2 en varchar2

Tags: oracle-11g, caracteres

tengo una tabla en Oracle XE 11.2 con un campo VARCHAR2(255 char) cuando hago un insert de un texto que tenga caracteres especiales como (ç,ã,ê) me considera cada caracter como 2 bits y me genera error ORA-12899 porque si el texto es de 255 caracteres y tiene un **ã** aparece que son 256 caracteres, lo curioso es que en otro equipo tengo la misma base montada pero en Oracle 11G Standard edition y ahi no me suma 2 bits los caracteres especiales, que puede ser lo que esta ocacionando esa diferencia?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de cómo esté configurada tu BD, el locale que definas al instalar.

Para usar esos caracteres, seguramente tienes alguna versión de AL32UTF8. Para representar un conjunto de caracteres va a usar 1 byte (no son bits), que son 8 bits.

Para conjuntos Unicode adicionales al ASCII extendido, regionales, alfabetos diferentes al latino, se requieren caracteres multibyte (no nos alcanzan los 8 bits para listarlos todos, se añadieron después) y van a ocupar 2 bytes cada uno. Si tú usas estos caracteres, vas a tener ese riesgo en campos en los que puedas usar una longitud mayor y definas la longitud máxima (`VARCHAR2(256)`) porque ese valor máximo del campo **es en bytes, no en carácteres**.

Revisa qué te da correr `SELECT LENGTH('çãê') FROM DUAL;` Y `SELECT LENGTHB('çãê') FROM DUAL;`.
Declarar el campo `VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)` mitiga este riesgo. El máximo es de 4000 bytes y 2000 CHAR para un campo VARCHAR2.

Ahora, si tienes `(255 CHAR)`, el problema no debe ser que haya un ç,ã,ê ahí dentro, sino que debes tener un carácter no visible que se está yendo junto a los demás. En teoría, al menos.

Sin tener una prueba que podamos replicar, es difícil decirte en tu caso específico qué puede estar pasando. Si en otro equipo está otra instalación 11G que funciona, te cuento que esto NO es una característica que sea propia de versiones standard o enterprise. Lo que yo revisaría es con qué LOCALE se instaló cada una, pues es posible que hayan usado WE8ISO8859P1 en una y AL32UTF8 en otra, por lo que el conjunto de carácteres va a variar de una a otra.

Comment: comparto el log de diferencia entre los dos equipos

INSERT INTO TNST_LOGS(LOGS_CODI, LOGS_DAHO,LOGS_MENS,LOGS_MEN2,EMPR_UTIL, LOGS_ESTA)
    VALUES (:LOGS_CODI, :LOGS_DAHO,:LOGS_MENS,:LOGS_MEN2,:EMPR_UTIL, :LOGS_ESTA)
'TNST_PROD.PROD_CODI=478TNST_PROD.PROD_DESC=çççãTNST_PROD.PROD_TIPO=1TNST_PROD.PROD_CONS=0TNST_PROD.CAPR_CODI=NuloTNST_PROD.UNME_CODI=9TNST_PROD.PROD_DOSE=0TNST_PROD.EMBA_CODI=NuloTNST_PROD.PROD_BARR=NuloTNST_PROD.IVAS_COD1=1TNST_PROD.IVAS_COD2=NuloTNST_PR'

    ORA-12899: valor muito grande para a coluna "CAS"."TNST_LOGS"."LOGS_MEN2" (real: 259, máximo: 255)

Comment: @lycros revisa lo que pusiste en el comentario. Eso va en la pregunta, no acá. Y no vemos nada de los datos usados ni de la configuración de la instancia, no cambia nada de lo que digo en la respuesta